# How to create a table with variable cell widths

Tags: tables, formatting, width, column-width

I try to recreate the following table in overleaf: 
[image]

What would be a clever solution? I tried to use \columnwidths and the cals package, but that didn't worked well.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? One way to solve of your problem is nesting tables in the second column.

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! I didn't know that it would be that easy. I didn't know that you can nest tables.

Comment: I would simply stack 5 tabularx with no vertical spacing.

Answer (score 2):

As starting point -- converting comments below answer to an code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%---------------- show page layoutdon't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l | L |} 
    \hline
Dimension   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Characteristika}  \\
    \hline
Feature Selection
            &   {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L|L|L @{}}
                xxx &   yyy &   zzz
                \end{tabularx}}                     \\
    \hline

some text   &  {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}L|L@{}}
                xxx &   yyy
                \end{tabularx}}                     \\
        \hline

some longer text
            &   {\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L|L|L|L|L @{}}
                uuu &   vvvv    &   xxx &   yyy &   zzz 
                \end{tabularx}}                     \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)